# How do I get UTC times and unixtimes to match in MYSQL server?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, utc

I have two timestamps in different formats.

One is a UTC string that looks like this: `"2014-09-19T20:55:51Z"`

The other is a unix timestamp that looks like this: `1411159809`

These two timestamps happen to be five minutes apart. As I verified with this [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) tool.

I want to put both of these time stamps (along with the data that they describe) into my database, but when I do they don't agree.

The table I'm using looks like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| property_key | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| updated_at   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| created_at   | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| value        | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| name         | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

As queries, I have:

`insert into events (value,property_key,created_at) values ('datapoints/56892923',273827,'2014-09-19T20:55:51Z')`

and

`insert into events (value,name,created_at) values ('240','HeartRate',FROM_UNIXTIME(1411159809))`

When I pull these entries back out of the database, this is what I get:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 1
property_key: 273827
  updated_at: 2014-09-19 17:42:44
  created_at: 2014-09-19 20:55:51
       value: datapoints/56892923
        name: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          id: 2
property_key: NULL
  updated_at: 2014-09-19 17:43:09
  created_at: 2014-09-19 14:50:09
       value: 240
        name: HeartRate
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`updated_at` becomes the timestamp for the creation of the row, as expected.  What bothers me is that `created_at` is six hours different.  I'm guessing MYSQL is interpreting the UTC as local time, but that's not what I want.  How do I get these timestamps to behave the way I want?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the table definition for `events` (i.e. the entire `CREATE TABLE` statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the manual for `FROM_UNIXTIME()`:

> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. ***The value is expressed in the current time zone***.

Also for the definition of the `TIMESTAMP` data type:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

So, if you're using `TIMESTAMP` columns you should be OK, all you have to do is use `TZ_CONVERT` to ensure the timestamp gets formatted as UTC.

Comment: Okay, if I'm understanding right, then TIMESTAMP expects its input to be in the current timezone.  So, I need to translate my UTC time stamp string to the current timezone before I store it.  It looks like I can do that with `CONVERT_TZ('2014-09-19T20:55:51Z','GMT','SYSTEM')`